# Open Activity from Android Alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-alarms

i've found these Toturials for an Alarmmanager:
http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/android/android-creating-alarm-alarmmanager

It's one that is not using Broadcast.

But it is not saying what I should put into my Manifest-File thus an Activity starts.

I've tried the following, but none of these work:

```
<receiver android:name="alarm.starter.AlarmReceiverActivity"></receiver>
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverActivity"></receiver>
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiverActivity"></receiver>
```

Please Help

Comment: can you post your entire Manifest?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use any BroadcastReceiver, so you don't need to add any `<receiver>` tags to the manifest. The alarm just starts an Activity. You just need to declare your AlarmReceiverActivity in an `<activity>` tag. You don't need the `intent.setAction()` call either.

Answer (score 0):

u need to add action string in manifest file,, Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366332/making-an-alarm-program-not-working/11366469#11366469)  answer may be it will help you

Although the code u shared just now, shows that you are not starting any receiver you are using activity so add below lines in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".AlarmReceiverActivity"/>
```

Comment: May be this makes no changes, but you will need to  add it, add ut and add your code in question, have u tried setting setAction in intent.

Comment: Ok, Here my Files:

Sorry, i coul't work with the Code-Format-Tool here.
[Pastebin][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/zJTdy4fi

Comment: in your code, I dint see any receiver , you are calling an activity with the alarm, should actually add your alarm receieverActivity into activity tag. I am going to edit my answer follow it.